# SQL - join, if multiple rows then choose based on column data

Tags: sql, teradata

I am joining two tables (Account,Address) based on a column called acc_id

The Address table sometimes have multiple addresses associated to an acc_id, and they are distinguished with a type column, that marks if the address is a primary or a secondary address.

I would like to join the two tables on the acc_id, the Address table's columns should be the following in the result:

- If no address, then null
- If 1 address exists, then the columns of that address
- If 2 addresses exists, then the columns of the primary address

How to do this in (Teradata-)SQL?

Comment: if you provide full table structure I could update my answer to use your specific columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

case statements could work for you!

- do a left join on the "Address" table twice.
- One of the join conditions should be for the "primary" address
- and the other for the secondary address.
- The case statements first check for the primary address
- and if one doesn't exist
- then select the secondary address.
- Since a `left outer join` is being used if neither exists the value will show as `NULL`

```
      SELECT DISTINCT a.acc_id
           , CASE WHEN primary_add.acc_id IS NOT NULL 
                  THEN primary_add.address 
                  ELSE secondary_add.address
             END address
           , CASE WHEN primary_add.acc_id IS NOT NULL 
                  THEN primary_add.city
                  ELSE secondary_add.city
             END city 
           , CASE WHEN primary_add.acc_id IS NOT NULL 
                  THEN primary_add.state
                  ELSE secondary_add.state
             END state 
           , CASE WHEN primary_add.acc_id IS NOT NULL 
                  THEN primary_add.zip
                  ELSE secondary_add.zip
             END zip 
           , CASE WHEN primary_add.acc_id IS NOT NULL 
                  THEN primary_add.address_type
                  ELSE secondary_add.address_type
             END address_type
          ------------------------------------------------
         FROM account AS a
          ------------------------------------------------
         LEFT OUTER JOIN address AS primary_add 
           ON     a.acc_id = primary_add.acc_id 
              AND address_type = 'primary'
          ------------------------------------------------
         LEFT OUTER JOIN address AS secondary_add 
           ON     a.acc_id = secondary_add.acc_id 
              AND address_type = 'secondary'
```

Comment: wouldn't using **coalesce** be simpler/easier to read ... but maybe harder to explain :-)? e.g.: COALESCE(primary_add.address, secondary_add.address) AS address

Comment: good point lexu, coalesce would definitely make the SQL example a bit cleaner.  Thanks for the edits

Comment: I am sure the answer is correct, but I could not test it properly, because the address is actually comming from a very complex view, and when I join this complex view with itself it takes extreme amount of time...

Comment: if the address is coming from a complex view, try simplifying the view and the data you pull back from it, and put it in a `volatile table`.  Use the volatile table in the above query and it could help speed things up for you

Comment: Oh and COALESCE resulted bad data, because if both primary and secondary address existed, and the primary address contained SOME null values, then the primary and secondary address values got mixed up. So acc_id checking is neccecary.

Comment: @kori0129: good comment regarding coalesce returning unexpected results .. wouldn't happen if you assigned default values to the data fields in account .. but that might well be out of your hand :-)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a much simpler Teradata solution:

```
SELECT   a.acc_id
       , b.*
FROM     account a
LEFT JOIN address b
ON      b.acc_id=a.acc_id
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.acc_id
                           ORDER BY     b.address_type) = 1
```

`QUALIFY` is a Teradata extension and very handy for things like this.  A partition is built using the `PARTITION` BY clause and sorted by the `ORDER BY` clause.  Then `QUALIFY` will keep the first row in each partition using the `ROW_NUMBER` function.

Of course, I'm assuming that your **address_type** column has values that sort as you want. If the values are in fact "Primary" and "Secondary", sorting in ascending order as shown should work (selecting "Primary" when both values exist).  You can also use a `CASE` expression in the `ORDER BY` clause if needed.

I'd also strongly suggest explicitly naming the columns wanted for your **address** table.  Your comment about wanting "nulls" for no addresses implies you need a `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: If "Primary" and "Secondary" is ordered descending, won't that mean that Secondary will be chosen,as S is later in the ABC than P?

Comment: @kori0129 Sorry, yes; "Secondary" would be selected first.  I misread the original question and I'll correct the answer.  But I think you get the idea.